# Unable to use TextMeshPro, only TextMesh available in Unity Code

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the text of a textmesh pro in my unity project, so I added a TextMeshPro Text Component to my GameObject. Now, when I try to write `TextMeshPro textmeshPro = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();`, I get the Error that TextMeshPro is not available in the Namespace. I used the import `using TMPro;`. The only thing available is `TextMesh`. Is this the Code equivalent to `TextMeshPro`?

Also, TMP_Text is not working for me. There are no suggestions form VS 2019 other than "TextMesh"

My Full Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ContextMenuInteraction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string partName;
    public GameObject assignedGameObject;

    
    void Start()
    {
        TextMesh Test = assignedGameObject.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
        TextMeshPro textmeshPro = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void showNearContextMenu (GameObject target)
    {
        //use position of game object to spawn context menu near it
    }
}
```

My TextMeshPro Object looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Did you configure TMP?  I know there was an initial step to get it setup in your project.

Comment: Afaik I did that. I had a popup saying "Import TMP Essentials" and I can change the TMP Text manually in the Gameobject. Even the import "TMPro" gets accepted. Its just that my Visual Studio complains that it cannot find "TextMeshPro" or anything related

Comment: Try rebuilding the project files.  Edit > Preferences > External Tools > [Regenerate Project Files]

Comment: This fixed it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild the project files. Edit > Preferences > External Tools > [Regenerate Project Files] - Problem solved by @hijinxbassist in the comments below the post

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the component Type. You need find the component with this Type "TextMeshProUGUI" this is the text component for UI.

Example:

```
TextMeshProUGUI nameField;
nameField = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
nameField.text = "some text";
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp688.png)

For me correct
I think change compiler for example Vscode or VS or rider